# Windows Phone 8 Launcher-App submits wrong width and height to the website when set to landscape

Tags: javascript, css, xaml, windows-phone-8, landscape

Iam working on a Launcher-App which launches my website. On the mobile Internet Explorer it's working fine(Landscape mode) but when I try to do it with my own app, which is fixed to landscape mode and has a webbrowser included, the WebBrowser sends the wrong width and height to my website (480x800) but it has to be 800x480 because of landscape.

Is there a solution for this problem or any workaround?